# django prevent empty model being saved

Tags: django-models

Is there a way to stop a model in django allowing an empty model to be saved?

e.g. I have a simple contact form

```
class Contact(models.Model):

alphabetical = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphabetical characters 
are allowed', 'Invalid input')

name = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[alphabetical])
email = models.EmailField(validators=[EmailValidator, ])
subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
message = models.CharField(max_length=250)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I prevent an empty model being saved? e.g. in the django shell I can do

```
contact = Contact()
contact.save()
```

This gives a model with all blank values saved.

Answer (score 0):

for validation you have to use [django.forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform). django forms will manage the validation part:

for eg: if your `model.py` is:

```
class Contact(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

now create a view in `views.py` :

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.models import Contact

def manage_contacts(request):
    ContactFormSet = modelformset_factory(Contact, fields=('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ContactFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid(): # check the validation for blank fields
            formset.save()
            # do something.
    else:
        formset = ContactFormSet()
    return render(request, 'manage_contacts.html', {'formset': formset})
```

create a template in `templates/manage_contacts.html`:

```
<form method="post">
    {{ formset }}
</form>
```